# Find empty tag in `xml` using Unix command

Tags: awk, sed, xml

The `xml` file gets generated with empty tags is like this

```
<headertag>
</headertag>
```

It's in consecutive lines and i usually use a perl script to find it based on new line character between tags as pattern (\n) but  Unix environment which I'm using now isn't supporting this perl script. Tried the same with sed but i couldn't find the place (line number) where there is a empty tag like this in a huge `.xml` file. Is there a solution to find this using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: The correct solution might be to use a proper XML parser... but that shouldn't be impossible for the usual text tools. What do you want to do with the empty tag if you find it? Remove it? Print its  line number?

Comment: Also, if you don't have Perl, but need to use `awk` or `sed`, it might be useful to know which versions of them you have. We know GNU tools have some useful non-standard extensions...

Comment: What sets the restrictions on your Unix environment, if I may ask? Management, technology, space, specification or something else?

Comment: Like perl commands need to be enabled by Unix admins, in big organization it difficult to reach and change configuration

Answer (score 2):

To parse XML, use an XML-aware tool.  I know you said you have restrictions on the system you're on, but I'm going to give you a solution that will work once you convince your manager/whatever that for robust and reliable operation, you need to install XMLStarlet to do proper XML parsing.

With XMLStarlet, given the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <headertag>
    <subtag/>
  </headertag>
  <headertag>
    <subtag>Don't delete me!</subtag>
  </headertag>
  <headertag>
</headertag>
  <headertag>
Not empty
</headertag>
</root>
```

the following removes all empty tags, no matter what their names are or where in the document they occur:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//*[not(normalize-space())]' file.xml >newfile.xml

$ cat newfile.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <headertag>
    <subtag>Don't delete me!</subtag>
  </headertag>
  <headertag>
Not empty
</headertag>
</root>
```

The `xmlstarlet` command may sometimes be called just `xml` depending on how it's packaged on your system.

XMLStarlet is available here: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/
... but see if your default package manager has it first.

Comment: I tried it! That's also not supported in my Unix environment

Comment: "Not supported" as in `xmlstarlet` is not installed and you don't realize you can simply install it, or you don't want to install it, or it cannot be installed?

Answer (score 1):

You have not told us what you want to do with the empty tags.  I am therefore going to assume that you wish to convert such tag pairs into the format `<headertag/>`

Here is a simple `sed` script which will do exactly that for the example case you provided us:

`sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s#<([^>]+)>\n</\1>#<\1/>#g' infile > outfile`

Comment: I need the line number where this pattern occurs

Comment: Not pretty but this should work: `sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s#<([^>]+)>\n</\1>#<\1 FPM>\n/>#g' file | sed  '/FPM/=' | sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s#<([^>]+) FPM>\n/>#<\1 />#g'`

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- Empty tags that we are after are on a line by themselves.
- The closing tag is also stands on it's own line + it immediately follows.
- Whitespace is assumed to compose of spaces and not TABs.

---

```
sed -ne '
   /^ *\(<[^><]*>\) *$/!d                                   # tag opening should be on a line of its own
   s//\1/                                                   # strip away all whitespace
   $d; N                                                    # if the tag opening is on the last line, we dont need it. Otherwise, we grab the next line
   s/^.\(.*\).\n *<\/\1> *$/Empty tag: <\1> on line num\#/p # print only in case the tagnames match across lines => we have found an empty tag
   /\n/!=                                                   # print empty tag line num
   D                                                        # delete the pattern space
' yourfile.xml
```

Comment: For something looking as complicated as that, you'd better provide an explanation. Especially since this is potentially going into a production system on at some company (judging from the comments to the question).

Comment: @Kusalananda Done .

Answer (score 0):

You can use "pcregrep" instead of grep which supports multiline patterns and has more options.

This pattern finds two consecutive lines containing open and close tags:

```
pcregrep -M -v "<headertag>\n\s*?</headertag>" file
```

- which -M stands for Multiline
- -v stands for inverse match
- \n is newline character supported in pcregrep but not grep (I think)
- \s is space character.
- *? any character

this pattern removes all empty tags.

Comment: PS. xml close tags contain </tag> not <\tag>, anyway this command works for both

Comment: The `.*` causes this to find any non-empty span which starts with a newline, and could straddle over a close and another open tag.  From `<p>\nmoo</p><p></p>` it will match `\nmoo</p><p>` between the first `<p>` and the last `</p>`.

Comment: @tripleee yes unfortunately I couldn't make a better pattern, and I guess this tag styles <tag>\n something<tag> is less likely to be found in code, I should mention this in answer, tnx

Comment: `'<headertag>\n\s*?</headertag>'` would fix these things.